# Finding intersection of two files with ordering maintained

Tags: java, algorithm, file-handling

I have two files say file1.txt and file2.txt. Both the files contain some contents separated by a `<TAB>`

for instance file 1 contains

```
123abc       us.online.com
ab123        us.online.co
```

file 2 contains

```
123abc       us.zhang.com
456def       us.ppd.456def
def56        cn.online.pek
ab123        us.portlet.co
```

Now i need to find the intersection of this two files in java based on first field namely. So my output should be basically

```
123abc       us.online.com       123abc       us.zhang.com
ab123        us.online.co        ab123        us.portlet.co
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in Java? This is what I have tried so far

```
   List<String> logRid = new ArrayList<String>();
   List<String> fatalRid = new ArrayList<String>();
   File logFile = new File("logs.txt");
   File rtlaFile = new File("rtla.txt");
   BufferedReader reader = null;

public List<String> readFiles(){
                    try
                    {
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFile));
                            String text = null;
                            while((text = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                    logRid.add(text);
                            }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try
                    {
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rtlaFile));
                            String text = null;
                            while((text = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                    fatalRid.add(text);
                            }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return this.intersection(logRid, fatalRid);
            }
public <T> List<T>  intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
            {
                    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

                    for (T t : list1) {
                            if(list2.contains(t)){
                                    list.add(t);
                            }

                    }
                    return list;
            }
```

I am able to get the intersection , only problem is maintaining the order.

Comment: What algorithm/logic you tried? please post your code?

Comment: I think the simplest way is to use Maps (HashMap). Just 1) parse your files into two maps, 2) combine two maps in single foreach loop

Comment: I concur with the Map idea; however, only one Map is required the 2nd file can be processed immediately (and can also be used to maintain ordering if it matters). If the keys in both files are (or could be) sorted, then a trivial 2-way merge loop would do. Alternative, load the data into SQLite first xD

Comment: I have added the code that I have tried so far. Only issue is maintaining the order,

Comment: What if one file has `abc x\ndef x` and the other has `def x\n abc x`? 'Maintaining the order' will be impossible.

Comment: Why isretaining the order important?

Comment: Retaining the order is important as there is an implicit relationship between the two.

Comment: What do you mean with maintaining the order? Can you give a counter-example and, possibly, how your code fails?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily if you first sort the two lists. Then do a straight merge.

If order is important, use a stable sort. Merge sort is stable.

Another way to do it would be to build a hash table from one list, and go through the other list, checking each item against the hash table. Here it's important to know which "order" you want things in. For example, if you have list A and list B:

```
List A
------
foo    whatever
bar    whatever


List B
------
bar    whatever
foo    whatever
```

If you want the result to be "foo, bar", then you create the hash table from List B. If you want the output to be "bar, foo", then create the hash table from List A.